# Undefined variable node in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am using zaptech theme in Drupal 6 while I am upgrading existing site to Drupal 7 it give me the error`: Undefined variable: node in include()` ,`themes\zaptech\page.tpl.php` can anyone tell what the solution for the node object

Comment: You have followed the [upgrade instructions](http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/6/7) haven't you?  I can't find reference to a *public* Zaptech theme anywhere, are you sure there is a D7 version of your theme?

Answer (score -1):

Remove it unless you have an automatically loaded node associated with it.